# Downloading an attachment from Inbox using the command-line

Tags: linux, command-line, email, fetchmail

Please help me figure out the right program to use to solve the following:

Everyday I have a report emailed as a PDF attachment to my inbox.  The subject is the same, and it is from the same email address.  I would like to be able to use a utility like fetchmail / getmail to reach into my inbox, match the subject and sender, and then download the attachment to a specific file.

Please help me identify the programs needed to:

1. Connect to my Inbox
2. Scan Subject Line and From Line
3. Download attachment from email
4. Delete from Inbox
5. Send processed report to new person.

I run CentOS7, but any Linux should be fine for this task.  Also, I'd like to use command line utilities for this task rather than Python or Ruby.

Additional information:

- My email is stored on a Server on my LAN.
- I think IMAP is what I want to use here (I'd like to keep the email on the server and only download the attachment)
- I don't need to view the attachments, only download them into a directory.

Sorry to bother everyone with this question, but I've done research on this, but I can't seem to put the pieces of the puzzle together.  Please let me know if there is any additional information you need.

Comment: Updated my question with the information you asked for.

Comment: That's a lot of pieces. If you can reduce your question to one piece, you are more likely to get answers. And can't you do any part of this? And some details about the use case could be helpful.

Comment: You didn't explain about your mailbox, but if you can use procmail and fetchmail, then see this post (https://kuther.net/howtos/howto-receive-mail-and-save-attachment-fetchmail-procmail-and-metamail) for how to extract attachments from emails.

Comment: You say you'd "like to use command line utilities [...] rather than Python or Ruby".  Is there a reason you're avoiding these/any scripting languages?  Once you've written the script (using an existing IMAP library, such as [imaplib](https://pymotw.com/2/imaplib/)) you should be able to run it like any other command line utility.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [mutt](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/). Install mutt, procmail and fetchmail. Mails will be stored here by default `$HOME/Mail/` (your maildir; create). Help to [setup Gmail in mutt](https://www.linux.com/blog/setup-mutt-gmail-centos-and-ubuntu). Setup [fetchmail](https://www.linux.com/news/fetching-email-mutt), [procmail](https://elatov.github.io/2010/02/procmail-installation-and-configuration-guide/) create an attachment directory

Add this to the $HOME/.procmailrc

```
ATTACH=`echo $HOME/Mail/Attachments`
:0 c
* ^To:.*me@email.com
* ^From.*notification@email.com
* ^Subject.*SUBJECTNAME
| munpack -q -C $ATTACH
```

`$ATTACH` directory will contain the filtered attachments (create). Specify `SUBJECTNAME`, `To`, `From`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're into peeping somewhat deeper down the DIY well, you could do something with an `expect` script over an `openssl` process, by adapting the quite clear and straight-forward instruction of https://delog.wordpress.com/2011/05/10/access-imap-server-from-the-command-line-using-openssl/

That uses IMAP over SSL to access the mailbox and obtain the headers for some emails. You'll need to do the same, although only pick emails with special headers for collating their indexes, and then fetch their attachment parts into files.

The exact script would be around 8 IMAP commands with corresponding `expect` stanzas. You might need to refer to RFC3501 for these, especially for the variations to the FETCH command.